# Using ng-href doesn't use interpolated values, while the value can be used in plain text

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I'm aiming to have various cards of different users referencing a model that I've created within the typescript file. I'm able to fetch the image, and the name, but there's trouble with having it read within the tags.

**HTML:**

```html
<div *ngFor='let person of people' class="card">
        <div class="imgBx">
        <img src="{{person.image}}"> <!-- This gets the image properly -->
        </div>  
        <div *ngFor='let social of person.socials' class="contentBx">
            <a ng-href="https://twitch.tv/{{person.username}}" target="_blank"><h2>{{person.username}}</h2></a> <!-- This gets username fine -->
        <div class="color">
          <span><a ng-href="https://twitch.tv/{{social.twitch}}" target="_blank"><svg img"></svg></a></span> <!-- This is where the link doesn't work -->
          <span><a ng-href="https://twitter.com/{{person.username}}" target="_blank"><svg img></svg></a></span> <!-- also tried approaching it differently and didn't work still -->
          <span> {{social.twitter}} </span> <!-- Meanwhile this fetches the variable just fine -->
          <h1><a ng-href="https://twitch.tv/{{social.twitch}}">{{social.twitch}}</a></h1>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Example of person object in .ts**

```
people: any[] =[
    {
      username: 'userName',
      image: 'link to image url',
      socials: [
        { twitch: 'userTwitch'},
        { twitter: 'userTwitter'},
        { instagram: 'userInstagram'}
      ]
    },
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you trying to use here? I am seeing a mix of angular and angularjs. Do you understand they are different things?

Comment: I generated the project with the Angular CLI 11.2.7, I am aware they are both different things, it's just been a while since I've really touched base on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing angular1 `ng-href` with angular 2 code which is wrong.

The equivalent of `ng-href` is href tag with property binding like `[href]` using this javascript expression can be written inside

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  people: any[] = [
    {
      username: 'userName',
      image: 'link to image url',
      socials: [
        { twitch: 'userTwitch' },
        { twitter: 'userTwitter' },
        { instagram: 'userInstagram' },
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let person of people" class="card">
  <div class="imgBx">
    <img src="{{ person.image }}" />
    <!-- This gets the image properly -->
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let social of person.socials" class="contentBx">
    <a [href]="'https://twitch.tv/' + person.username" target="_blank"
      ><h2>{{ person.username }}</h2></a
    >
    <!-- This gets username fine -->
    <div class="color">
      <span
        ><a [href]="'https://twitch.tv/' + social.twitch" target="_blank"
          ><svg img></svg></a
      ></span>
      <!-- This is where the link doesn't work -->
      <span
        ><a [href]="'https://twitter.com/' + person.username" target="_blank"
          ><svg img></svg></a
      ></span>
      <!-- also tried approaching it differently and didn't work still -->
      <span> {{ social.twitter }} </span>
      <!-- Meanwhile this fetches the variable just fine -->
      <h1>
        <a [href]="'https://twitch.tv/' + social.twitch">{{ social.twitch }}</a>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lx4pee)